# Check if a namedspaced class exists

Tags: ruby, constants

I'm writing a helper to check if a given class exists.

```
def safe_constant(constant_sym)
  return Object.const_get(constant_sym) if Object.const_defined? constant_sym
end
```

This works just fine for something like `safe_constant(:User)`

However, we have a number of objects that are namespaced in modules

`safe_constant(:Admin::User)` is obviously not a valid symbol. I know I could determine if this exists by doing:

`Object.const_get(:Admin).const_get(:User)` but before I go writing some kind of split loop drill-down method to get the final constant, is there any standard way to handling this already?

Comment: Is it a hard requirement to accept the class name as a symbol? Because testing it as a string is much easier: `Object.const_get('Admin::User') rescue nil`.

Comment: I tried doing this initially, but it gave the error: `wrong constant name Admin::User`

Answer (score 1):

According to Ruby API document, it's possible to get [const_defined?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Module.html#method-i-const_defined-3F) and [const_get](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Module.html#method-i-const_get) working with namespace string to check and return the class constant. What needs to be done is passing the second argument (`inherit`) as `false`, for example:

```rb
class User; end

module Admin
  class User; end
end

Object.const_defined?('Admin::User', false) # => true

Object.const_get('Admin::User', false) # => Admin::User
```

PS: [const_defined?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Module.html#method-i-const_defined-3F) and [const_get](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Module.html#method-i-const_get) do not accept namespaced Symbol and will raise NameError exception, for example:

```rb
# namespaced String
Object.const_defined?('Admin::User', false) # => true

# namespaced Symbol
Object.const_defined?(:'Admin::User', false)
# => NameError (wrong constant name Admin::User)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
def safe_constant(constant_sym)
  return constant_sym.to_s.constantize if valid_constant? constant_sym.to_s
end


def valid_constant?(const)
  const.constantize
  return true
rescue NameError
  return false
end
```

Comment: Note that the `constantize` method comes from the activesupport gem.